# Cannot get certain characters imported into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, csv, utf-8, character-encoding

This issue is absolutely killing me, I cannot get a single solution online to work!

I am trying to import the following text from a CSV to a MySQL table - via Navicat's import wizard:

```
L154 – TRAINING WARRANTY
```

The hyphen is a wide hyphen and so far I've managed to import it as either a question mark, or a black diamond with question mark inside. Same for £ symbols and other special characters.

[image]

Everyone always talks about UTF-8. So far I have tried:

Saving the CSV in Excel, clicking Tools > Web Options > Encoding: UTF-8

Right clicking the database and clicking EDIT. Setting Char set to utf8 Unicode and Collation: utf8_general_ci

I have "designed" the table and set the 2 options above to exactly the same.

I have edited the varchar field in question and set the same 2 fields again to the 2 types above.

But my hyphen will not import correctly.

It would be nice to know exactly how to go about importing data that has £ symbols and other special characters once and for all.

Comment: I use "latin1_swedish_ci" for the table and the varchar field and just tried to save "£" and it worked for me.

Comment: That's not a "hyphen", it is an "en dash".  The hex (in UTF-8) is 3 bytes: `E28093`.  If you can get the hex of the csv file, please confirm.  Meanwhile, don't use `latin1` for the table/column, use `utf8` (or utf8mb4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>You can use `htmlentities()` to store these symbols in encoded form like e.g.</s>

`£` will be `&pound;` and `–` will be `&ndash;`, by using:

```
echo htmlentities('£');
```

and when retrieving, just use `html_entity_decode()` Like:

```
echo html_entity_decode('&pound;'); // output £
```

**Edit:** As discussed in the comments, how you are trying to import the data from a CSV file. You have to change the encoding for the CSV file, which can be done using Notepad++, By going to `Encoding->Encode in UTF-8`

Comment: Hi Mega. I'm not using PHP until the data is being output on the page. It's being stored via an import so htmlentities doesn't come into play here.

Comment: I have set Char Set to UTF8 in the table options - and every text/varchar field in that table to utf8 and I still get the diamonds. This seems an impossible situation!

Comment: Just to add to this - this query works and the hyphen inserts correctly. So it seems to be struggling to deal with the CSV: insert into table_name SET Name = 'L154 – TRAINING WARRANTY'

Comment: It worked!!!! Can't believe it. I can live with re-saving the imports each time. Thank you so much. Can you add that as a new answer and I will vote?

Comment: Just running some tests - it seems I need to export the data as XLSX if I want to edit the data back in Excel. If I export as CSV the data looks like this: L154 â€“ TRAINING WARRANTY - is that what you would expect?

Comment: @JamesWilson Yes, that looks like `ANSI` to me, you can easily convert that to UTF-8 too, via the Npp

Comment: I exported to to XLSX. Opened in Excel, edit the file, saved as CSV. Opened the CSV in NotePad++, converted to UTF-8 - imported successfully to DB. I'm happy with that procedure!